# Circumscribed sphere about a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, spheres

$ABCD$ is a tetrahedron such that $AB=2\sqrt{3}$, $BC=\sqrt{7}$, $AC=1$ and $AD=BD$. Plane $ABD$ is perpendicular to plane $ABC$. Find the shortest distance between lines $BD$ and $AC$ if the radius of the circumscribed sphere about the tetrahedron is equal to $2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that $\triangle ABD$ is acute. Let $P$ be the center of the circumscribed circle about $\triangle ABC$ and $Q$ be the center of the circumscribed circle about $\triangle ABD$. Consider a line $p$ that passes through point $P$ and is perpendicular to plane $ABC$. Similarly, let $q$ be a line that passes through $Q$ and is perpendicular to plane $ABD$. Denote $O=p\cap q$. We've thereby constructed a point which is equidistant from the vertices of the tetrahedron and is thus the center of the circumscribed sphere about the tetrahedron. Note that $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse and hence point $P$ lies outside it, so $O$ must lie outside the tetrahedron. So far so good.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. $DA=DB$ yields $DM\perp AB$. On the other hand, $OM\perp AB$ as $OA=OB$. The dihedral angle between the two perpendicular planes $(ABC)$ and $(ABD)$ is therefore $\sphericalangle QMP=90^\circ$. Note that $MPOQ$ is a quadrilateral with three right angles so it must be a rectangle, meaning that $OP=MQ$. We'll come back to that in a bit. Let's calculate the radius of the circumscribed circle about $\triangle ABC$. We calculate $\sphericalangle BAC=30^\circ$ and now we can use law of sines to calculate the radius, which is simply equal to $\sqrt{7}$. Consider the right $\triangle BPO$ where $BO=2\sqrt{2}$ and $BP=1$. The Pythagorean theorem gives us $OP=1$ which, according to our previous observations, is also equal to $MQ$. From here we easily calculate $QB=2=QD$ so $MD=3$ and hence $AD=BD=2\sqrt{3}$.

To find the shortest distance between lines $BD$ and $AC$, I suggest that we choose a point $N\in (ABC)$ such that $ABNC$ is a parallelogram. Here's a sketch of what we've done for now:[image]

Note that $AC\parallel (BND)$ and $BD\subset (BND)$ so the shortest distance between these lines would be equal to the distance between an arbitrary point from $AC$ to plane $(BND)$. Let that point be $C$. In order to calculate the required distance, we need to find the volume of $BNCD$ (which is equal to the volume of $ABCD$) and the area of $\triangle BND$. Let's calculate the volume first. The height of the tetrahedron is $DM=3$ and we easily calculate $S_{ABC}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. We therefore obtain $V_{ABCD}=V_{BNCD}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. To find the area of $\triangle BND$. We have $\cos\sphericalangle ABD\cos\sphericalangle ABN=\cos\sphericalangle DBN$ and so $\cos\sphericalangle DBN=-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$ (because $\sphericalangle ABD=60^\circ$ and $\sphericalangle ABN=150^\circ$). Therefore, $\sin\sphericalangle DBN=\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{4}$, which we find using the well known Pythagorean identity $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$. We thus have $S_{DBN}=\dfrac{\sqrt{39}}{4}$ and so we're finally ready to find the required distance, which I'm going to denote by $d$. We have $\dfrac{d\sqrt{39}}{12}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $d=\dfrac{6\sqrt{13}}{13}$. The case when $\triangle ABD$ is obtuse is left as an exercise to the OP. A very interesting problem indeed.